# Dependencies error while trying to use country selector in my react code

Tags: reactjs, rxjs, jsx

I am trying to modify a code in .jsx to include a country selector and for that I am using the **country-region-selector** package using npm

After I install it in my ubuntu, and I am trying to run the code however I am getting this error :

```
     [ERROR] Could not resolve "react"

    ../../node_modules/react-country-region-selector/dist/rcrs.es.js:1:48:
      1 │ import React, { Component, PureComponent } from 'react';
        ╵                                                 ~~~~~~~

  You can mark the path "react" as external to exclude it from the bundle, which will remove this
  error.

11:29:46 AM [vite] error while updating dependencies:
Error: Build failed with 1 error:
../../node_modules/react-country-region-selector/dist/rcrs.es.js:1:48: ERROR: Could not resolve "react"
    at failureErrorWithLog (/home/shamma/my-experiment/client/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:1605:15)
    at /home/shamma/my-experiment/client/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:1251:28
    at runOnEndCallbacks (/home/shamma/my-experiment/client/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:1034:63)
    at buildResponseToResult (/home/shamma/my-experiment/client/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:1249:7)
    at /home/shamma/my-experiment/client/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:1358:14
    at /home/shamma/my-experiment/client/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:666:9
    at handleIncomingPacket (/home/shamma/my-experiment/client/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:763:9)
    at Socket.readFromStdout (/home/shamma/my-experiment/client/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:632:7)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:315:12)
Vite Error, /node_modules/.vite/deps/react-country-region-selector.js?v=8daa6a38 optimized info should be defined
```

The line of code  I am using in my code to include the package it this -->

```
import { CountryDropdown, RegionDropdown, CountryRegionData } from 'react-country-region-selector';
```

I looked online and I install the peer dependencies and save props using npm like that -->

```
(base) shamma@shamma-ThinkPad-13-2nd-Gen:~$ sudo npm-install-peers
This package doesn't seem to have any peerDependencies
(base) shamma@shamma-ThinkPad-13-2nd-Gen:~$ 
(base) shamma@shamma-ThinkPad-13-2nd-Gen:~$ sudo npm install --save prop-types
npm WARN react-country-region-selector@1.4.7 requires a peer of react@^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-country-region-selector@1.4.7 requires a peer of react-dom@^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN shamma No description
npm WARN shamma No repository field.
npm WARN shamma No license field.
```

in the code there is a several packages for dependencies, one of them is -->>

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@empirica/core": "1.0.0-rc.21",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "18.0.14",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.0.5",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react-refresh": "1.3.6",
    "autoprefixer": "10.4.7",
    "path": "0.12.7",
    "vite": "2.9.15",
    "vite-plugin-restart": "0.1.1",
    "vite-plugin-windicss": "1.8.4"
  },
  "name": "my-experiment-empirica-server",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "build": "vite build",
    "dev": "NODE_ENV=\"production\" vite",
    "serve": "vite preview"
  },
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "volta": {
    "node": "16.17.0",
    "npm": "8.15.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete the node_modules & package-lock.json and try npm install

or run `npm audit fix`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Remove your node_modules folder (`rm -rf node_modules`)
2. `npm cache clean -f`
3. `npm install`